# Does Android have a comparable solution to iOS Saliency Analysis?

Tags: android, computer-vision

On the iOS framework you can run a saliency analysis on an image and then crop that image based on the foreground subject.

See this article: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/cropping_images_using_saliency

Is there a comparable solution or third-party library for Android?

Comment: Google promotes [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) so searching on that topic may give results. On mobile Google has [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) and the closest seems to be [Selfie segmentation (BETA)](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/selfie-segmentation) There is also [MediaPipe](https://mediapipe.dev/) from Google which has a number of [solutions](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/solutions.html)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm specifically looking for a process that will identify a rectangle book cover in the foreground when being held. So the Selfie segmentation doesn't really work. Not sure if any of the Media Pipe stuff would work or not.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do [object detection](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/object-detection) but if none of the prebuilt solutions works for your use case (i.e. always ignore person) you may need to go with a [custom model](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models), perhaps with [transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning). Good luck.